# How to put MVC partial view into a lightbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, lightbox

So I have a shared Layout. I want to have a search form on that layout. When the search is made I want to return the results into a lightbox. I am not the greatest with JS. Here is what I have:

Shared Layout:

```
<div id="search-form">
@Html.Action("Search", "RespondentSearch")
</div>
<div id="search-results">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Whitelist]
public ActionResult Search()
{
     return PartialView("_SearchFormPartial");
}

[HttpPost]
[Whitelist]
public ActionResult Search(string query)
{
     return PartialView("_SearchResultsPartial");
}
```

SearchFormPartial View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "RespondentSearch", FormMethod.Post,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "search-results"
        },
        new
        {
            @class = "sidebarSearch"
        }
        ))
{
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="respondent search..." id="ac" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" />
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <input type="submit" value="" rel="lightbox" />
    </div>
}
```

Search Results Partial: (this entire table is what i want to be inside Lightbox)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Stuff in Here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you asking for the jQuery code to call the `Search(string query)` action, or the C# code to filter the results?

Comment: I would use an ajax call for this. Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126058/how-can-i-pass-a-value-entered-in-a-texbox-to-a-partialviewresult/19385495#19385495

Comment: I am looking for the jquery code that will put the searchresults partial view into a lightbox

Comment: Not quite sure I understand Matt Bodily could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it:

Shared View:

```
        <div id="RespondentSearch">
            @Html.Action("Search", "RespondentSearch")
        </div>

        <div id="search_results" style="display: none">
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Whitelist]
public ActionResult Search()
{
     return PartialView("_SearchFormPartial");
}

[HttpPost]
[Whitelist]
public ActionResult Search(string query)
{
     return PartialView("_SearchResultsPartial");
}
```

The Form in a shared view (the heart of it all)

```
<div class="sidebarSearch">
    <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="respondent search..." id="ac" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" />
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
    <a href="#search_results" rel="lightbox" id="performSearch"></a>
</div>

<script>
    $('#performSearch').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("Search", "RespondentSearch"))",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { query: $('#query').val() },
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#search_results").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```