# Create a popup that renders a partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, popup

I've been struggling with a popup for the last few days. Here's a little information. I am very new to using JavaScript, but I'm eager to learn. First of all [here is an example of what I want to make.](http://beta.directopdracht.nl) (Press 'Inloggen' on the top right corner to make it pop up) The CSS is no problem. I got this working using [bPopUp](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) and copying editing the code used in the site, not the [examples](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bpopup/).

But anyway, the site demonstrated here is made using php. But my boss decided to switch to MVC 4 .NET. Which isn't really a problem, except for the fact that it doesn't work anymore. And I don't know why.

So I decided to start over, but I could use a little help.

What I would prefer to achieve is to have one `<div>`  that can be re used and renders a partial view.

To trigger it I would like something in the lines of:

```
       <span class="popup_button white" data-popup="Some/view" data-height='200'>Inloggen</span>
```

This may be other tags instead of span and Id can be used instead of class to define it's a pop-up trigger. (Any entire other solutions are welcome as well of course).  I would like the use the data-popup attribute to specify which partial view to render when triggered and the data-height attribute to specify the height of the content of the popup.

Can anyone one give me tips on how to reach this? I know it might be much to ask, but every suggestion is welcome. Due to my inexperience with JavaScript I prefer code examples, but any architectural suggestions will be happily accepted.

Thank you guys in advance :D

Comment: numerous modal's support integrated ajax content... keep doing some searching. Lots to chose from without re-inventing the wheel

Comment: @charlietfl I have done a lot of searching, but I couldn't find what I want or I didn't recognize it as the thing I wanted. So, if you have any suggestions please help out.

Comment: searching for open source plugins can be frustrating, and eat up plenty of time. But, if you are very new to javascript, is time well spent . Creating a demo in jfiddle.net of what you have so far helps a lot too

Comment: use an ajax call back to the controller.  See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126058/how-can-i-pass-a-value-entered-in-a-texbox-to-a-partialviewresult/19385495#19385495.  That will populate your div with the partial and you can just run your overlay on it.  Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @MattBodily Thank you for your answer, but honestly I have no idea how to handle that piece of code and what it does. So some extra explaination would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#my-button').click(function () { 
    var BaseUrl = "/Popup/" + $('#my-button').data("popup"); 
    $.ajax({
        url: BaseUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: { Id: $('.Id').val() }
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            $(".content").html(result);
            //There are different ways to do the pop up.  you mentioned you had the popup working.  trigger it here
            $('#popup').fadeIn("slow"); 
            $('.fader').fadeIn("slow"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Action(int Id){
    //populate a model
    return PartialView("_PartialViewName", model);
}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm gonna try it soon. Actually the popup now inserts an iframe into the .Content div.  So i guess i still need to do that? 

What is the job of the `url:"@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",` line?

Comment: Iframes have their uses but from what I understand should generally be avoided.  In the Url.Action replace those with your action and controller name.  That will do an async call to the controller which will return a partial view that in my code will be inserted into a div which you can then do a popup on

Comment: Okay, I started out by actually following the bpopup example and this is what i've got so far <http://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/7713/>. But even this works on JSfiddle, but not in my project.

Comment: `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>`
`<script src="/Scripts/scripting.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`
`<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>`
These are my imports

Comment: your jsfiddle gives a 404.  My code will work for you.  You should look at jquery dialog or overlay.  We went for overlay for the look and implementation.  In that case in my code set the html of the div and then just do overlay.load()

Comment: From what I can see it should be simple to combine what is in your example with my code.  I added a couple edits to my code.  Using the div from your fiddle I changed my selectors and added the popup load from your fiddle to my code.  See if that works for you

Comment: But the thing that i've got in JSFiddle right now isnt even working :( at least not in my Project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40968/discussion-between-roxas-and-matt-bodily)