# How to render a partial view (using razor) after user click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been searching for a solution, but every thing I tried didn't help, although it seems very easy. I'm sure some of you will know what should I do.

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 (razor).
I have a side menu, and all I want is that another partial view will be rendered (depends on the menu item's being clicked).
I have a div on my page that should contain this partial view. The command:

```
 @Html.Partial("_TitleDescription")
```

works just fine, but it's statically render the partial view (on compilation time). I want it to render it dynamically with every button the user clicked in the menu.

I tried:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Location", "Location", "Product",  new { id = @Model.ID }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET"})
```

I tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function getView() {
            $('#detailsDiv').load("@Url.Action("Location" , "Product" )");
        }
 </script>
 <a href='javascript:getView();'>Get Partial View</a>
 <div id="detailsDiv"></div>
```

and also like this:

```
 <div id="detailsDiv">
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("_TitleDescription", null); }
 </div>
```

but nothing works for me.

---

EDIT:

I tried the two answers but non of them works... so here is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Location(int id = 0)
    {

        Product product = unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetById(id);

        return PartialView("Location.cshtml", product);
    }
```

I put a breakpoint and I'm hitting it every time, but still nothing is changing in the view... :(

This is what i tried again:

```
 <div id="detailsDiv"></div>
 <a href="#" onclick="loadLocation()">Location</a>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadLocation() {
            $.get('@Url.Action("Location","Product", new { id = 15 } )',
                 function (data) {
                     $('#detailsDiv').load(data);
                 });
        }
 </script>
```

and I also tried this:

```
 <div id="detailsDiv"></div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Pages","Location","Product",new {id = 15},new {@class="menu"})

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".menu").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                $("#detailsDiv").load($(this).attr("href"))
            });


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Add your controller code

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897157/create-a-popup-that-renders-a-partial-view/19909810#19909810

Comment: Can you check the jQuery request in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Here is my controller code and my view code @Murali

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pages","Pages","Home",new {@is=Model.ID},new {@class="menu"})
@Html.ActionLink("Posts","Posts","Home",new {@is=Model.ID},new {@class="menu"})
<div id="detailView"></div>
```

And have some javascript to listen to the click event on these links and use jQuery load method to load the result from the action methods.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

    $("a.menu").click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      $("#detailView").load($(this).attr("href"))

    });

  });
</script>
```

Assuming you have the Action methods in your `HomeController` which returns the relevant view/partial view.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $.get( '@Url.Action("Location","Location", new { id = Model.ID } )',
 function(data) {
        $('#detailsDiv').html(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different side menus for different (partial) views, have you considered using sections in the main Layout? this is one of the ways of sorting this kind of problems.

For instance the main `_Layout.cshtml` (e.g. in Shared folder would look as follows:

```
@{
    string result = null;
    if (IsSectionDefined("Navigation"))
    {
        result = RenderSection("Navigation", false).ToHtmlString();
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Title"))
    {
        <header id="top">
            <h1>@RenderSection("Title")</h1>
        </header>
    }
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Navigation"))
    {
        <nav>
            @Html.Raw(result)
        </nav>
    }
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
                @if (IsSectionDefined("SideMenu"))
                {
                    <td>
                        <aside>
                            @RenderSection("SideMenu")
                        </aside>
                    </td>
                }
                <td>
                    <section>
                        @RenderBody()
                    </section>
                </td>
                @if (IsSectionDefined("SideMenu2"))
                {
                    <td>
                        <aside>
                            @RenderSection("SideMenu2")
                        </aside>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Navigation"))
    {
        <nav>
            @Html.Raw(result)
        </nav>
    }
    <footer>
        <h4>The footer of the main Layout</h4>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And then three different view could define sections:

Example of View 1:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cieties";
}

@section Title
{
    Main cities around the World
}

@section Navigation
{
    Home | City 1 | City 2 | City 3  
}

@section SideMenu
{
    <ul>
        <li>Population</li>
        <li>Area</li>
        <li>History</li>
        <li>For turists</li>
    </ul>
}

@section SideMenu2
{
    <ul>
        <li>Additional link 1</li>
        <li>Additional link 2</li>
        <li>Additional link 3</li>
    </ul>
}

<div>
    Here goes everything about particular city
</div>
```

Example of View2:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cars";
}

@section Title
{
    All about good cars
}

@section Navigation
{
    Home | BMW | VW | Nissan  
}

@section SideMenu
{
    <ul>
        <li>Fuel consumption</li>
        <li>Comfort</li>
        <li>Technical details</li>
        <li>Engine</li>
    </ul>
}

<div>
    Here goes everything about particular Cars
</div>
```

Example of View3:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Food";
}

@section Title
{
    Tasty food for all occasions
}

@section navigation
{
    Home | Non-vegetarians | Vegetarians | In 30 mins | Spanish Tapas  
}

@section SideMenu2
{
    <ul>
        <li>Spanish cusine</li>
        <li>Italian cusine</li>
        <li>American fast food</li>
    </ul>
}

<div>
    Here goes everything about particular food
</div>
```

A few sections are optional that is why I have put `false` as a second parameter of `@RenderSection()`. You would need to work out CSS for this and perhaps `<nav>`, `<section>`, `<aside>` as part of HTML5 would need to be changed to `<div>` tags but that's the minor change.

Kust a side note: you need to call `@Layout = ~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` in order for MVC 4 to call this layout for all Views.